# Is it possible to read French characters into a C# string from an .eml file?

Tags: c#, regex, string, pdf, file-conversion

I have a project where I need to generate a .pdf file based on the content in an .eml file.  When dealing with just english characters, I'm fine, the pdf is created flawlessly and everything works (after I strip all the needless html junk).

However an issue arrives when I try to read in an .eml file that is filled with french characters.  In particular the french characters are stored as number codes like =E9, =E8, &#339, so on and so forth.

So my issue is this.  I read the .eml file in with:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

However it comes in as plain text and I don't know how to make the system interpret the =E9 and =E8, etc., codes as French Characters.  I can always Regex.Replace everything but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.  Is there any way to take in that long string of plain text and interpret the codes embedded within properly so that the french characters appear instead of their respective codes without using like 30 Regex.Replace expressions?

Due note I can't use any built in iTextSharp functionality since I also need to be able to incorporate french characters (pulled from that .eml file) into the file name of the pdf.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexes, but two regexes should be enough:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"=([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})", match => ((char)uint.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"&#(\d+);", match => ((char)uint.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value)).ToString());
```

A different way would be to find a MIME parsing library which exposes methods for parsing parts of MIME messages, that way you'd decode the `=E9` codes. Then, you'd need to call `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` to parse the HTML entities.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, it's not exactly what I was going for but it's definitely a more elegant solution than what I had planned before.

Comment: Oh BTW, since you seem to have HTML content you should definitely replace the second line with `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`.